# How do I expose Scala constructor arguments as public members?

Tags: scala

Look at this example:

```
class Point(x: Double, y: Double){
  override def toString = "x: " + x + ", y: " + y
  def +(sourcePoint: Point) : Point = {
    return new Point(x + sourcePoint.x, y + sourcePoint.y
  }
}
```

As you can see I want to define a `+` operator method on the Point class. But this won't work
because in that method, `x` and `y` can't be accessed on the `sourcePoint` local variable since they are private, so I changed the example into this:

```
class Point(_x: Double, _y: Double){
  var x = _x
  var y = _y

  override def toString = "x: " + x + ", y: " + y
  def +(sourcePoint: Point) : Point = {
    return new Point(x + sourcePoint.x, y + sourcePoint.y)
  }
}
```

That obviously worked, however is there an easier way to define these variables instead of going from _x -> x and _y -> y.

Thanks for help and time! :)

Comment: When you write `class Point(x: Double, y: Double)`, `x` and `y` are just parameters for the primary constructor, not fileds in the class. To make them fields of the class, you need `val` or `var`.

Comment: Aight, thanks! Seems obvious now haha ;)

Comment: This is a little OT, but don't use explicit return in your '+' method, explicit returns in scala get translated to an exception that is thrown and directly catched and then the result is returned. Only use this to break out of closures.

Comment: @drexin I've just checked quickly with the scala REPL and javac: you're wrong, it's transformed into a catched exception only on nonlocal return.

Comment: @Nicolas oh, thanks. You're right. But nonetheless returns should be implicit.

Comment: Yes, it's more idiomatic. But with your explanation, I would never ever used a recursive function ;)

Answer (score 73):

Yes, there is:

```
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

Comment: I feel embarrassed. I should do my homework better how could I skip this :P

Comment: @user1285925 If you wanted to keep `x` and `y` private they you'd need to add `private` before each `val` in the constructor argument list.

Comment: @LeifWickland Is there a reason ever to declare `private val` in the argument list? You could just leave it out and the compiler makes it a field if necessary.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge By default, the compiler made `private[this] val`. It leads to the issue mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5):

using `val` is valid but then the parameter becomes final (constant). 
If you want to be able to reassign the value you should use `var` instead. So

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int)
```