# Using class parameters to assign field value

Tags: java, scala, class

I'm new to scala and would like to use class parameters to assign the value to a field of the same. In Java, we do similar thing within a constructor:

```
public class Test{

    private final int value;

    public Test(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to do a similar thing in `Scala`:

```
class Test(value: Int){
   val value = ..WHAT..value //Is there a way to assign a parameter value to a field with the same name?
}

object Test{
   def testMethod = //access value and do something with it.
}
```

Can we do something similar to what we can in do in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I expose Scala constructor arguments as public members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864111/how-do-i-expose-scala-constructor-arguments-as-public-members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala provides a shorter syntax for creating such a member - just add the keyword `val` before the argument name in the class parameter list. You can also add a modifier (e.g. `private`):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Test(private val value: Int)

object Test {
  def testMethod(t: Test) = t.value
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Test
defined module Test

scala> Test.testMethod(new Test(5))
res1: Int = 5
```

Comment: AFAIK, it will make it a public member. As a Java programmer, we don't quite like making class members be public. Is it common in Scala?

Comment: @user3663882 Scala follows Uniform Access Principle. Check out.http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-nine-uniform-access/

Comment: Huh, didn't think that we can declare such things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like exposing a private member, you could go for this:

```
class A {
  private var _quote = ""
  def quote = _quote
  def quote_=(newQuote: String) = _quote = newQuote
}
```

Which would you give you a getter and setter, both accessible by calling `quote`.

Comment: You can also make that `private var`, with its default value, an optional constructor parameter.