# Scala usage of public vals

Tags: java, scala, oop

I came from Java and like most Java programmers I read J. Bloch's effective Java in which he suggests minimizing fields access level as much as possible. I was kind of surprised by the fact that such strong frameworks like `akka` use public vals like this:

```
trait Actor {

    type Receive = Actor.Receive

    implicit val context: ActorContext = {
       //ommited for simplicity
    }


    implicit final val self = context.self //MUST BE A VAL, TRUST ME

    //...
}
```

Is it common in Scala to use public `val`s? And what is the convention for this? Because in Java, I would definitely not make fields public under  general circumstance. (Of course, there might be cases where private fields are impractical, but that's definitely an exception).

Comment: In Scala, Uniform Access Principle is often advised http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-nine-uniform-access/ Also, refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095679/using-class-parameters-to-assign-field-value

Comment: One of the possible reasons: Java does not have good support for immutable values. So there is danger of some outside code changing them. Vals in scala are immutable and Scala encourages the use of vals instead of vars. So no harm in exposing immutable vals to the outside world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, instead of public fields, getters and setters are used whereas Uniform Access Principal in scala necessity to use getters and setters.

http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-nine-uniform-access/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in exposing mutable state. If your method is pure and variable is immutable, no unsafe things can happen.

However, if you want to keep APIs clean, you always can hide them with `private/protected[...]`.